# How do I make the update query executed by JdbcPollingChannelAdapter transactional?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-integration, spring-transactions

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration

public class IntergrationMain{
@Bean
public MessageChannel aChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
@Splitter(inputChannel = "inChannel", outputChannel = "outChannel")
public List<myEnity> splitter(Message message) {

}
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "2000"))
public MessageSource<?> pollDbForQuery(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter myAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, SQL); 
    myAdapter.setRowMapper();
    myAdapter.setUpdateSql("update query");
    retrun adapter;


}
```

}

I want to make the update query that is executed by the jdbcPollingadapter to become transactional. I saw some examples on the web but they were using a builder for Pollers and provide transaction support by setting a method called `setAdvice()`. I'm not able to achieve something similar using the JdbcPollingChannelAdapter  right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `@Poller` annotation:

```
/**
 * @return The {@link org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata} bean
 * name.
 */
String value() default "";
```

So, you need to configure a `PollerMetadata` bean with a `PeriodicTrigger` for that `Duration.ofSeconds(2)`. And there is a `setAdviceChain()` option where you can inject a `TransactionInterceptor`.

And that is clearly explained in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#configuration-using-poller-annotation

Comment: I've followed the steps but I'm not sure how I test that transaction is actually working. I enabled these options in my app.props 
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor = TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG But I'm not able to see any transaction for the update query exeuted by the polling adapter.

Comment: The `@InboundChannelAdapter` is performed on a scheduled thread. We need to see what you are really doing in your test. Do you block it for some data to receive from the `outChannel`?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041632/how-to-configure-a-transactioninterceptor-equivalent-to-the-transactional-annot